# Read shapefile into pysal

Tags: python, shapefile, pysal

I've found the following Python module to work out the Mean Nearest Neighbor Distance Statistics of points

https://pysal.org/notebooks/explore/pointpats/distance_statistics.html

I've successfully installed the required modules as stated

```
import scipy.spatial
import libpysal as ps
import numpy as np
from pointpats import PointPattern, PoissonPointProcess, as_window, G, F, J, K, L, Genv, Fenv, Jenv, Kenv, Lenv
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

My issue is this part ...

```
points = [[66.22, 32.54], [22.52, 22.39], [31.01, 81.21],
          [9.47, 31.02],  [30.78, 60.10], [75.21, 58.93],
          [79.26,  7.68], [8.23, 39.93],  [98.73, 77.17],
          [89.78, 42.53], [65.19, 92.08], [54.46, 8.48]]
pp = PointPattern(points)
```

I have a shapefile `test.shp` with  `x y and z` columns within it. I want to read in the points contained in the shapefile - but I'm unsure how to?

Comment: What have you tried, because there are many questions/ansvers in GIS SE about reading a shapefile with Python , even with PySal ?

Answer (score 2):

Whith Pysal or libpysal  you don't need geopandas to read a point shapefile

```
import libpysal 
from pointpats import PointPattern
shp = libpysal.io.open('point.shp')
pp = PointPattern((pt[0],pt[1])  for pt  in shp)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`geopandas`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/)

```
import geopandas as gpd
from pointpats import PointPattern

gdf = gpd.read_file('points.shp')
pp = PointPattern([[p.x, p.y] for p in gdf.geometry])
```